# Sending data as input in IOTA

Tags: transaction, iota-network, security

I am Muhammad, working with my way to use IOTA to fetch data from IDS/IPS. IOTA uses 2 transactions as input if I am not wrong. I want to send data of IDS to IOTA. I am using Grafana and mysql to store data but Idk how to send it as direct input to IOTA.

What I am trying to do is "send IDS/IPS data to IOTa and then  I want IOTA to share that data to another device using IOTA", (my prime goal right now is to let IOTA fetch IDS/IPS data as input and I don't know how I am supposed to that). If anyone can provide me some guideline or helping material that make me understand how it is supposed to work like my ideal condition or to nearest condition to solve my this dilemma will mean a lot, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Umair's answer is the correct one, but I just wanted to add that it's free to send only data in a transaction. We call this a [zero-value transaction](https://docs.iota.org/docs/getting-started/0.1/transactions/transactions#zero-value-transactions). Once a transaction is on the Tangle, anyone can read it as long as it isn't encrypted, for example using a restricted or private channel in [Masked Authenticated Messaging](https://docs.iota.org/docs/client-libraries/0.1/mam/introduction/overview).

We recently updated the documentation portal, so the links that Umair used are [here](https://docs.iota.org/docs/client-libraries/0.1/how-to-guides/js/send-your-first-bundle) for sending a transaction and [here](https://docs.iota.org/docs/client-libraries/0.1/how-to-guides/js/read-transactions) for reading a transaction (in Node.js).

Comment: Thanks Umair and Jake. You guys are truly a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

You can use official [client libraries](https://docs.iota.org/docs/client-libraries/0.1/introduction/overview) for sending transactions to the tangle.

[Here](https://docs.iota.org/docs/iota-js/0.1/workshop/send-your-first-bundle) is an example of sending data to the tangle. An example of reading transactions from the tangle can be found [here](https://docs.iota.org/docs/iota-js/0.1/workshop/read-transactions).